# Ivygen Error when I add ivy

Tags: python, add-on

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Roaming\Blender   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\add_curve_ivygen.py", line 583, in execute
IVY.grow(ob)
File "C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\add_curve_ivygen.py", line 322, in grow
self.maxAdhesionDistance)
File "C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\add_curve_ivygen.py", line 408, in adhesion
adhesion_vector = ob.matrix_world * nearest_result[0] - loc
TypeError: Matrix subtraction: (Matrix - Vector) invalid type for this operation

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Any help?

Comment: Please upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add a link to your answer

Comment: @TLousky I don't think it really matters. It's an empty scene with just a cube. When I have it selected and try to add ivy, I get the error.

Comment: But why is there (1) in .py file name - `add_curve_ivygen (1)` ? Do you have 2 files of add_curve_ivygen ?

Comment: @MrZak Yeah I downloaded it from a different place to make sure it wasn't the wrong file.

Comment: @Chickenator Well there you go then, use the default one included in blender. You probably downloaded an outdated plugin.

Comment: @Rielight Just used the default one. I'll edit for the new error.

Comment: @Chickenator Oh and another question, are you using newest version of blender?

Comment: @Rielight Yup. I have it on steam so it auto updates. I am 100% sure I'm using 2.77

Comment: @Chickenator Okay, go to where your addon is located and try opening it with a text editor and replace it with this: http://pastebin.com/aCGbBYqq

Comment: @Rielight Still an error.

Answer (score 1):

Old question. I'm using Blender 2.79, but I had the same issue. I also didn't realize IvyGen comes pre-installed with blender; and after installing it I got this issue.

Blender doesn't overwrite plugins (at least this version - I can't vouch for 2.77, but I'd doubt it). Instead, it stores plugins in the AppData directory. I got this error, which clarifies:

[image: IvyGen - duplicate plugin error]

After deleting the copy of the plugin from my AppData, then restarting Blender, I'm able to enable the correct copy of the plugin, and it now runs fine.

Note that, adding an ivy curve to a Blender default startup file with a cube may not appear to work immediately. This happened to me because my cursor was inside the cube, since the ivy (as when any other objects are added via Shift+A) grows from the 3D cursor's location.

Comment: Hope I clarified. My 3D cursor was inside the cube (at <0,0,0>); and the ivy - growing from it - was thus also inside the cube.

Comment: Indeed ivy will appear on cursor location (0,0,0 default), either it should be repositioned before running addon or one should look for the ivy object in the viewport or Outliner